# How to get @borrows tag working in JSDoc

Tags: jsdoc

I have been having a hard time getting the @borrows tag working in JSDoc. I have been trying to get the documentation from one function and us it as documentation for a second function. But I don't seem to be able to even get a simple example working!

```
/**
 * This is the description for funcA
 */
var funcA = function() {};

/**
 * @borrows funcA as funcB
 */
var funcB = function() {};
```

I was expecting this to output documentation for both functions with both exactly the same. However only funcA is only has a description.

Answer (score 4):

The `@borrows` tag doesn't seem to work directly on a symbol, but only indirectly.  For example I had:

```js
/** does amazing things */
function origFunc = function() {};

/**
 * @borrows origFunc as exportedFunc
 */
exports.exportedFunc = origFunc;
```

but I, like you, got nothing useful in the generated doc.

That is because, it seems, that the `@borrows` tag operates on a *container*.  (If you'll notice in the examples the `@borrows` tag is on the "util" module/namespace, not the renamed symbol.)

So this worked for me:

```js
/** does amazing things */
function origFunc = function() {};

/**
 * @borrows origFunc as exportedFunc
 */
exports = {
  exportedFunc: origFunc,
}
```

Seems like a bug in `@borrows` though.  (Or at least a bug in the documentation.)

Comment: I guess no chance to get this workin with parameters (`@param`)?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a usage of it, what I was trying to do is to create a module and add some functions to it. The problem is that I don't have anything directly related to this module, since the export is just a line. Here's how I ended up with using `@borrows`.

```
/**
 * A typehead with options filtered by user input.
 *
 * @module Typehead
 * @borrows Typehead
 * @borrows TypedOption
 * @example
 * <Typehead />
 */
export { default } from './Typehead'
```

In this case, `Typehead` will be borrowed in either `Function` or `Classes` section of module page depending on the kind of `Typehead`, and it will be displayed under `@example` render.

**Note**: However `@borrows` will add some extra entries to the system, after some experimentation, maybe `@see` is a better use.